# htaccess Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a simple 301 redirect

From

> http://my-site.com/old-cat/old-sub-cat/ARTICLE_NAME

**.htaccess**

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old-cat/old-sub-cat/(.*)$
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new-cat/%1 [R=301,L]

**But**
as a result I get a new category without a slash

> http://my-site.com/new-catARTICLE_NAME

where I made a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional redirect in between? Also, why are you using RewriteCond for this instead of `RewriteRule ^/old-dat/old-sub-cat/(.*)$ /new-cat/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: There is no additional redirect and RewriteRule ^/old-dat/old-sub-cat/(.*)$ /new-cat/$1 [R=301,L] return 500 error... 
And I just want to get the missing slash :)

Comment: the `/new-cat/%1` with a `%` is mistake when writing the question or is how you have it in .htaccess? Because the correct way is with `$`, see @janh2 comment.

Comment: not a problem, I changed to $, but the result is the same **http://my-site.com/new-catARTICLE_NAME**

Comment: Very strange. Are there any other redirects that might be responsible? Have you set RewriteBase in your .htaccess?

Comment: If a RewriteCond  is used and you take a matching pattern from there than %1 is correct.  If you use a matching pattern from your RewriteRule only than you have to use $1

Comment: my entire file
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old-cat/old-sub-cat/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new-cat/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: just route aliases, to describe the structure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also work for you, you do not need a RewriteCond at all:

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-cat/old-sub-cat/(.*)$ /new-cat/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But your code is also right.

Browser tend to remember 301 redirects so it could be that this is not coming from your Server at all but from your Browser

It could also be that some other .htaccess maybe in some other directory or the Server configuration or the APP itself do some redirect.

Comment: there is one more .htaccess in the sub directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>

Comment: I feel completely stupid, you are absolutely right - I just forgot to clear the cache. Both options work correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: This happens to me also sometime, and I also forget about it and looking at the Code and find nothing ;-)